# Most common hour query?

Tags: mysql, datetime

I have this table:

```
ID(INT)    DATE(DATETIME)
```

Under the `DATE` column there are a lot of different dates, and I want to figure out the most common **hour** between all the rows of the table, regardless of the day.

How can I do that with a MySQL query?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT HOUR(date) AS hr, COUNT(*) AS cnt
FROM yourtable
GROUP BY hr
ORDER BY cnt DESC
LIMIT 1
```

relevant docs: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_hour

Answer (score 2):

Try this -

```
SELECT HOUR(`DATE`) AS `hour`, COUNT(*)
FROM `table`
GROUP BY `hour`
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do a query like:

> SELECT COUNT(`daterow`) AS `occurrences` FROM `table` GROUP BY `daterow` ORDER BY `occurrences` DESC LIMIT 1;

Answer (score 0):

SELECT COUNT( id ) , HOUR(  `date` ) 
   FROM  `test` 
   GROUP BY HOUR(  `date` ) 
   ORDER BY COUNT( id ) DESC 
   LIMIT 1